# How to iterate rows in pandas Dataframe to perform the Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

**How to iterate rows in pandas to perform the Manipulation in a format below**

I have a csv file that contains a 365 column and 1152 rows(the rows index is divided like(1,48),(1,48)...), I need to select K maximum rows from every (1,48) row index and perform some manipulation.

**Steps I took:**

I used df.apply to do this.

**Code I tried**

```
def with_battery(val):
    for i in range(d2i.shape[0]):
        if i in [31,32,33,34,35,36]: #[31,32,33,34,35,36] should be replaced by top K max.
          #batterysize = 50
          if val.iloc[i]>batterysize:
             val.iloc[i]=0
          else:
             val.iloc[i] -= batterysize
    return val
D2j = D2i.apply(with_battery,axis=0)
```

**How the data is:**

```
**Input Dataframe**

        1   2   3   4   5   6   7
   1    10  11  34  21  23  12  10
   2    11  11  11  11  11  11  11
   3    32  32  32  32  32  32  32
   4    21  21  21  21  21  21  21
   5    42  42  42  42  42  42  42
   6    34  34  34  34  34  34  34
   1    21  21  21  21  21  21  21
   2    22  22  22  22  22  22  22
   3    54  54  54  54  54  54  54
   4    45  45  45  45  45  45  45
   5    43  43  43  43  43  43  43
   6    42  42  42  42  42  42  42


> for K=3, the row (3,5,6) is max so I made the value less than 50 as Zero and value more than 50 as value - 50. Similarly in next chunk of rows (3,4,5) is top 3 max rows and I performed similar action as above

Output Dataframe

    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   10  11  34  21  23  12  10
2   11  11  11  11  11  11  11
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   21  21  21  21  21  21  21
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   21  21  21  21  21  21  21
2   22  22  22  22  22  22  22
3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   42  42  42  42  42  42  42
```

Comment: can you provide a short abstract example (instead of 356x1152, let's say something 6x12 with repeats every 3 rows)? input and expected output

Comment: please provide the input as DataFrame constructors (**text**, not images)

Comment: is this fine now?

Comment: I figured it out how to do this, Thanks.